# celery celery_session_worker pytest timeout

Tags: pytest, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to write integration test for the celery tasks and have a test class like below

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_app')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_worker')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('mongodb')
class TestIntegration:
    def test_delete_collection_from_mongodb(self, x, y):
        results = delete_collection_from_mongodb(x, y).delay()
        assert results.get(timeout=20) == 20
```

And in my conftest I have the following fixtures

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': RABBITMQ_BROKER_URL,
        'shutdown_timeout': 30,
    }


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_worker_parameters():
    return {
        'queues': (....),
    }


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_enable_logging():
    return True
```

However, when I run the test it times out. Stacktrace:

```
task_id = '6009db28-637b-4447-a2c5-c0bdb3c03981', timeout = 10.0, interval = 0.5
no_ack = True, on_interval = <promise@0x7fcfaac01d30>

    def wait_for(self, task_id,
                 timeout=None, interval=0.5, no_ack=True, on_interval=None):
        """Wait for task and return its result.

        If the task raises an exception, this exception
        will be re-raised by :func:`wait_for`.

        Raises:
            celery.exceptions.TimeoutError:
                If `timeout` is not :const:`None`, and the operation
                takes longer than `timeout` seconds.
        """
        self._ensure_not_eager()

        time_elapsed = 0.0

        while 1:
            meta = self.get_task_meta(task_id)
            if meta['status'] in states.READY_STATES:
                return meta
            if on_interval:
                on_interval()
            # avoid hammering the CPU checking status.
            time.sleep(interval)
            time_elapsed += interval
            if timeout and time_elapsed >= timeout:
>               raise TimeoutError('The operation timed out.')
E               celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out.

/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py:792: TimeoutError
```

I've also tried to set the result backend to RPC, Redis, or cache+memory, and it still times out. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the celery version you are using it could be [this issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6521) which has been fixed since 5.0.4. It was root-caused to the cache backend, though I see you've tried other backends with the same result.

Is it possible your backend and/or broker arent up when you run the tests? I also saw this timeout error when testing in a docker setup with the broker, backend, and test code all running in separate containers. Blowing away all the containers & rebuilding fixed it for me, so it was probably some weird state.

The github issue offers [this minimum fixture & test case](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6521#issuecomment-739580159) that might be worth trying out to see if you can get that to work.